# Is there any wrong if we call a delegate method like our own methods

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I am calling a mkmapview delegate method (regionDidChangeAnimated) when the user clicked on a button. 
Is that the right way or not? 
Can we call delegate methods?

because, i have some code that has to execute we user pan the map, so when user pan the map automatically mapview delegate regionDidChangeAnimated called and i have to perform same action when user pressed a button.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether you can call the delegate method manually, then the answer is yes. You can.

However, it's probably not a best practice to do so. The mapView's delegate method should really only contain code that you want to run when the mapView calls it. What I would suggest is to take that code from the delegate method, and put it in a new method. Then call that new method from the delegate method (and whenever else you want).

This will ensure that in the future you can choose to add additional code that runs only in the map view's delegate method.

Comment: Thank you. I did the same like you said, but i just wanted to know is it right or not